# C++ Object doesn't save value

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

Objects I created for the `Player` class does not change the private variable even tho it does in the function that changes it. There maybe some reference problems with the objects being used in the `main()` function but I can't figure out where or why.

Specifically the loop at the end of the main file prints the games won by the players in the vector `Players` but all the scores return 0. While when the player `object.matchWon()` function correctly parse and print the score and shows the change made to the private variable.

I suspect there are problems with the usage of `getPlayer()` function in the main code.

Thanks in advance!!

`Player.cpp`:

```
#include "Player.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
//constructor
Player::Player(string first, string last) {
    Player::first = first;
    Player::last = last;
    gWins = 0;
    gLoss = 0;
    mWins = 10;
    mLoss = 2;
}

//setters
void Player::addLoss(int increment) {
    this->gLoss+=increment;
}

void Player::addWins(int increment) {
    this->gWins+=increment;
}

void Player::matchWon(vector<string> scores) {
    for (int i = 5;i<scores.size()-1;i++){
        cout<<(int)scores[i][0]-'0'<<"-";
        cout<<(int)scores[i][2]-'0'<<endl;
        gWins+=scores[i][0]-'0'; //add games won
        cout<<gWins<<endl;
        gLoss+=(int)scores[i][2]-'0';   //add games lost
    }
    this->mWins++;
}

void Player::matchLost(vector<string> scores) {
    this->mLoss++;
}

double Player::winPercentage() {
    return (double)mWins / mLoss;
}

//accessors
string Player::getFirstname() {
    return this->first;
}

string Player::getLastname() {
    return this->last;
}

int Player::getGameswon() {
    //cout<<gWins;
    return this->gWins;
}
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "player.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

vector<string> split(const string &s) {
    vector<string> elems;
    istringstream iss(s);
    do
    {
        string sub;
        iss >> sub;
        elems.push_back(sub);

        //cout << "Substring: " << sub << endl;

    } while (iss);

    return elems;
}

Player &getPlayer(vector<Player> &players, const string &first, const string &last){
    for (int i=0;i<players.size();i++){
        if (players[i].getFirstname()==first&&players[i].getLastname()==last){
            return players[i];
        }
    }
    players.push_back(Player(first,last));
    return (players[players.size()-1]);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    ifstream file(argv[1]);
    ofstream ofile(argv[2]);
    if (!file.is_open()){
        cerr <<"Could not open file\n";
        return 0;
    }

    string line;
    vector<Player> players;

    while (getline(file,line).good()){

        vector<string> lineParsed = split(line);
        vector<string> matchData = split(line);

        Player p1 = getPlayer(players,lineParsed[0],lineParsed[1]);
        Player p2 = getPlayer(players,lineParsed[3],lineParsed[4]);

        p1.matchWon(lineParsed);
        cout<<p1.getFirstname()<<"!"<<p1.getGameswon()<<endl;
    }

    for (int i=0;i<players.size();i++){
        //cout<<players.size();
        cout<<players[i].getFirstname()<<":"<<players[i].getGameswon()<<endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: look this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608535/passing-a-vector-by-reference-to-function-but-change-doesnt-persist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're copying your players:

```
Player p1 = getPlayer(players,lineParsed[0],lineParsed[1]);
Player p2 = getPlayer(players,lineParsed[3],lineParsed[4]);
```

so when you `p1.matchWon()`, it happens to the local `Player` object, not the one in the vector.

Although the return type of `getplayer()` is `Player&`, that doesn't matter if you're assigning it to a non-reference variable. If you want to be modifying the `Player` instances in the vector, you should have

```
Player& p1 = getPlayer(players,lineParsed[0],lineParsed[1]);
Player& p2 = getPlayer(players,lineParsed[3],lineParsed[4]);
```

By the way, `getPlayer()` is unsafe. The vector might resize itself when you `push_back` to it, invalidating references. You may want to store a vector of pointers instead (or just make sure through e.g. `resize()` that the vector definitely has room for all the players you want to push to it).

Comment: Thank you for the response!! When the vector resizes, it may change the internal references for stored variables? is that what you mean by invlidating references?

Comment: The contents of the vector may have to move to a different memory location. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261037/what-happen-to-pointers-when-vectors-need-more-memory-and-realocate-memory) for specifics.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you included the class definition. There seems to be something strange going on:

```
Player::first = first;
Player::last = last;
```

Are these static fields? If they are, the issue is that you only store the first and last (names?) of the last player you create.